# Recent Viewed Products not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php-5.4

I am written the code for Recent Viewed Products on footer.phtml, but it's not showing.

my code is:

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout>
    <default>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
                <action method="setIsHandle">
                    <applied>1</applied>
                </action>
            </action>
        </reference>


        <!-- Remove callouts and rarely used stuff -->
        <remove name="right.poll"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
        <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
 <reference name="footer">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed"
                                         template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </default>
```

**footer.phtml**

```
<div class="block-content">
                <!--?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/‌​product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?-->
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
            </div>
```

**shopper/default/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml**

```
<?php
ob_start();

/* @var $this Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed */


$helper = $this->helper('shoppersettings/image');
$imgX = 56;
$imgY = $helper->calculateHeight($imgX);
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $_products as $_product ) : ?>
            <li class="clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX, $imgY) ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgX*2, $imgY*2) ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgY; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$queldorei_blocks = Mage::registry('queldorei_blocks');
if ( !$queldorei_blocks ) {
$queldorei_blocks = array();
} else {
    Mage::unregister('queldorei_blocks');
}
$queldorei_blocks['block_viewed'] = ob_get_clean();
Mage::register('queldorei_blocks', $queldorei_blocks);
```

can you tell me where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the block in page.xml??

Comment: @dh47, Yes in local.xml i have added.

Comment: The code looks fine and works perfectly. Are you sure you have used `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>` code. Have you tried clearing the caches?

Comment: @Dexter, did you tried `footer.phtml` file or ?

Comment: @Dexter, sorry, it's returning error message `Not valid template file:frontend\base\default\template\reports/‌​product_viewed.phtml`.

Comment: @ManojKumar: Yes it tried your code in footer.phtml. Have you checked if the file `product_viewed.phtml` exists?

Comment: @Dexter, yes in my theme `reports/product_viewed.phtml` file is exist. Is need to call any where in `layout.xml` file?

Comment: no it is not necessary to call in layout.xml if you are calling it using getLayout(). Another way you can try is as below: in your local.xml file add code `<reference name="footer">
  <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
 </reference>` and call it in footer.phtml using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18988/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-dexter).

Comment: @Dexter, see my question is updated. suggest me where i went wrong?

Comment: are you using any third party extension to display recently viewed products?

Comment: @Dexter, yes. shopper theme

Comment: It seems there might be some issue with the theme.. try replacing the related product file of default theme with current file,... clear the caches and then check

Comment: how you are testing this?Actually your code is right. Recently viewed products only show when you just viewed any product.

Comment: @Dexter, now working i think third party code some how wrong. I will modify it. thank you..

Comment: I will summarize and write the answer down. You can accept and close the question so it can be useful for future user

Answer (score 3):

To call recently viewed product in your footer you can try as below:

in your `app/design/frontend/{yourTheme}/default/layout/local.xml` file add code

```
<reference name="footer"> 
   <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

and call it in `footer.phtml` using

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

The problem you are facing is because of the third party theme you have used. Clean up the code from `reports/product_viewed.phtml` and replace it with default file from `base` folder.

**NOTE: Always try the default Magento code if you face any errors in the theme to check the origin of error**