# reports/product_viewed block wont render at all

Tags: product, blocks

In trying to solve this issue Ive read [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268891/how-to-display-recently-viewed-products-list-on-product-details-page-magento) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682483/how-to-get-recently-view-product-for-guest-user-in-magento) [articles](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45453/recent-viewed-products-not-showing), and ended up trying to output the Recently Viewed Products file in a variety of ways, and none of them seem to be working.

Here is the relevant bits in `local.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="reports.product.viewed2" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I have these lines at the very top of `reports/product_viewed.phtml`:

```
<pre>hello</pre>
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
```

This is how I am trying to output the recently viewed products in `catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<hr>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reports.product.viewed'); ?>
<hr>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reports.product.viewed2'); ?>
<hr>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/‌​product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
<hr>
```

All of this outputs the following:

---

---

`hello`

---

---

Basically, the `product_viewed` file only outputs anything when it is inserted as a `core/template` block, but obviously it wont work properly unless its inserted as a `reports/product_viewed` block. However the `product_viewed` file wont render at all if its inserted as a `reports/product_viewed` block.

This is the same if I have logged into an account or if I am viewing the site as a guest.

Refreshing the statistics in the Admin Panel made no difference.

This is in Magento 1.9.2.2.

Does anyone have and ideas as to why my `reports/product_viewed` block wont render at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you disabled module output for `Mage_Reports` in System > Configuration > Advanced.

These settings don't really disable the module, but make all blocks of it output nothing.